# Algorithm problems, android java

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I've a problem but i really don't understand why. The problem is when i want to add an element in my `ArrayList`.
Here is my code :

```
    ArrayList<Integer> lesCasesCoches = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    lesCasesCoches.clear();
    Log.w("Test", "je beug pas" + idCasier);
    for (int f = 0; f < laCave.requeteIdCasier.size(); f++) {
        if (laCave.requeteIdCasier.get(f) == idCasier) {
            Log.w("Test", "size" + f);
            Log.w("Test", "id casier" + laCave.requeteIdCasier.get(f));
            Log.w("Test", "id case" + laCave.requeteIdCase.get(f));
            int casesAdd = laCave.requeteIdCase.get(f);
            Log.w("Test", "que vaut add" + casesAdd);
            lesCasesCoches.add(casesAdd);
            Log.w("test", "Cases cochés" + lesCasesCoches.get(f));
        }
    }
```

Here is my error log:

```
test: je beug pas2
test: size2
test: id casier2
test: id case5
test: que vaut add5
```

==> here the bug message

```
delvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception ( group=0x415072a0)
java.lang.indexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 1
```

Sorry for my bad english.
Thank you very much for the time you spend for me

Comment: Please post additional code to encompass all of the variables used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
Log.w("test","Cases cochés"+lesCasesCoches.get(f));
```

to

```
Log.w("test","Cases cochés"+lesCasesCoches.get(lesCasesCoches.size()-1));
```

Comment: Thank you very much ....
I think the probleme was with this line :

    lesCasesCoches.add(casesAdd);

So i don't think to look to the Log.w juste after.

Thanks you very much (:

Answer (score 1):

I think this make exception error.

```
Log.w("test","Cases cochés"+lesCasesCoches.get(f));
```

change this.

```
Log.w("test","Cases cochés"+casesAdd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things here:
1) why do you need to clear an Array you just created?
2) you access laCave.requeteIdCase and laCave.requeteIdCasier at the position f but f is only bound to laCave.requeteIdCasier.size(). That probably is crashing because requeteIdCase has lesser elements than requeteIdCasier (whatever those terms mean :) )

Comment: Because when i've a bug i try to make a lot of things ... wich are really stupid :/
And no they always have the same number of elements :)
Thanks you

Comment: No because the two array have the same number of elements so no problems with that. I just focus my brain on the line where i had elements in my array list, not on the log.w ... But with the help of all of your i can continue, thank you very much, my exam is tomoroow ^^"

Answer (score 0):

It probably happens because of this statement `if (laCave.requeteIdCasier.get(f) == idCasier)`
because if it's not true then for loop will go forward and increase f hence it won't match with

```
        lesCasesCoches.add(casesAdd);
        Log.w("test","Cases cochés"+lesCasesCoches.get(f));
```

so instead of getting f'th item you should get the last one

```
Log.w("test","Cases cochés"+lesCasesCoches.get(lesCasesCoches.size()-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is actually caused by logging:

```
Log.w("test", "Cases cochés" + lesCasesCoches.get(f));
```

Explanation:

```
test: je beug pas2
test: size2
test: id casier2
test: id case5
test: que vaut add5
java.lang.indexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 1
```

From the debug log, you add the **first** `Integer` 5 from `casesAdd` into `lesCasesCoches` when `f` is 2. Since this is the first time you add the number, the `size()` of `lesCasesCoches` is 1. Then, when you call the problematic line, you're trying to access the **third** (from 0-based index) element of `lesCasesCoches`, resulting in `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The solution is to either remove the line if it's not really needed, or to use `lesCasesCoches.get(lesCasesCoches.size() - 1)` to get the last added `Integer` from `lesCasesCoches`.